# How to use getParts in java to get only image parts?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, multipartform-data, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload a file to cloudinary. I'm stucked at how to only get parts of image from the form. It keeps on throwing exception: Invalid image file. If I remove all text inputs in the form, the uploading is successful. I guess that happens because the form also has text inside. Please help me solve this. I'm really grateful for your support.
Here is my code:
Form.jsp:

```
<form role="form" action="<c:url value="/admin/product/update"/>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="id" value="${product.id}" hidden="">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Name:</label> <input class="form-control" value="${product.name}" name="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Price:</label> <input class="form-control" value="${product.price}" type="number" name="price" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Quantity:</label> <input class="form-control" value="${product.quantity}" type="number" name="quantity" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Image:</label> <input class="form-control" value="${product.image}" name="image" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Description </label> <br>
           <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" value="${product.description}"  ></textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <select name="catid">
                      <c:forEach items="${categorylist}" var="c">
                           <option value="${c.id}">${c.name}</option>
                      </c:forEach>
                 </select>
            </div>
       </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label>image</label> <input type="file" name="image" value="${product.image }" />
            </div>
```

Servlet.java

```
        BeanUtils.populate(product, request.getParameterMap());
        //if (catid != product.getCategory().getId()) {
        //    Category category = new Category();
        category = dao2.getCategoryByID(catid);
        product.setCategory(category);

        Map result = null;
        Collection<Part> fileParts = request.getParts();
        for (Part part : fileParts) {
            String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
            result = UploadImage.uploadImage(fileName, part);
            String url = String.valueOf(result.get("url"));
            product.setImage(url);
            if (result == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Loi upload");
            }
        }
        
        dao.update(product);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudinary [upload method](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#file_source_options) supports uploading media files from the sources like a local path, a remote URL, a private storage URL (S3 or Google Cloud storage), a base64 data URI, or an FTP URL.

Based on your code, it seems that you are only supplying the filename of the image.

```
String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
result = UploadImage.uploadImage(fileName, part);
```

You would need to update the code to input the local path of the image.